# JQuery navigation menu doesn't change color when scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

does anyone knows why my navigation bar doesn't change color when I scroll down;
This is the nav bar:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</div>
```

And:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("div").scroll(function() { // check if scroll event happened
    if ($(document).scrollTop() > 50) { // check if user scrolled more than 50 from top of the browser window
      $(".navbar-fixed-top").css("background-color", "#f8f8f8"); // if yes, then change the color of class "navbar-fixed-top" to white (#f8f8f8)
    } else {
      $(".navbar-fixed-top").css("background-color", "transparent"); // if not, change it back to transparent
    }
  });
});
```

It doesn't work no matter what I've tried

Comment: You need to attach the scroll listener to `document`, not `"div"`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to attach the `.scroll` to `document` like this...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).scroll(function() { // check if scroll event happened
    if ($(document).scrollTop() > 50) { // check if user scrolled more than 50 from top of the browser window
      $(".navbar-fixed-top").css("background-color", "#f8f8f8"); // if yes, then change the color of class "navbar-fixed-top" to white (#f8f8f8)
    } else {
      $(".navbar-fixed-top").css("background-color", "transparent"); // if not, change it back to transparent
    }
  });
});
```